# What is summer in Spanish? "Estío" vs "verano"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

I have translated summer into Spanish. What is the difference between "estío" and "verano"?

RAE says that estío is verano.

Hypothesis: estío is used in poetry, verano in daily life.

Comment: Native Spanish speaker learning new Spanish words ✋

Comment: Spanish is my first language, and I have never heard of "estío". Use "verano".

Comment: Latin distinguished between _veranus_ (good weather) and _aestivum_ (hot season). After, _prima vera_ (first summer) was separated, leaving the word _veranus_ to refer to the early months of summer and _aestivum_ for the final months.

Comment: Interestingly enough, English uses "vernal" as an adjective for spring, as in "vernal equinox".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are right: they are absolute synonyms. And you are again right saying *estío* is commonly used in poetry: you would not find anybody using such word in a random, common conversation.

It is interesting to see the evolution of the usage of these words along time:

> [image]

A quick look to the list of [books using *estío*](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22est%C3%ADo%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_es&gws_rd=cr&ei=z9UNWMr0DoK0aYqOr9gF) reveals a lot of poetry.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complement [fedorqui's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18515/12637), it is interesting to note that when you use "summer" as an adjective (as in "summer season"), in Spanish the adjective *estival* is more used than *veraniego/a*:

[image]

So we can say *época [estival](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Gtt7xYk)*, it does not sound too formal. But between *estío* and *verano* as nouns, I agree with fedorqui.

Comment: It's a bit more used, but not by a lot.  It's hovering around 58-60%: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(estival%2Bestivales)+%2F+(estival%2Bestivales%2Bveraniego%2Bveraniega%2Bveraniegos%2Bveraniegas)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28estival%20%2B%20estivales%29%20/%20%28estival%20%2B%20estivales%20%2B%20veraniego%20%2B%20veraniega%20%2B%20veraniegos%20%2B%20veraniegas%29%3B%2Cc0  I feel like that's mainly in writing.  I don't think I've ever heard *estival* in casual speech.

Answer (score 4):

VERANO is the commonly used word and ESTÍO is a very unusual way to refer to the summer, and its use is more appropriate for literature or poetry.

Comment: True indeed. I am a Spaniard, born and raised there. Never in my live have I ever met someone who used the word ESTÍO. I think that it would be hard to find even in modern literature.

Answer (score 2):

*Estío* and *verano* are synonyms but *verano* is more usual and colloquial.
*Estío* is more literary.

Comment: Hola Joaquin y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que la respuesta actual es apenas un comentario. Intenta [editarla](/edit) para indicar referencias, ejemplos, etc y que así sea de mayor utilidad.